# How to get next sibling element on blur using event parameter (object) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am working on a form and I want to show validation message on next sibling element. I am using the `blur` event. I want to show the error in the next sibling element, but I am unable to do this using event property. It's giving me an error message:

> next() is not a method

How can I do this?

Comment: We can't debug code that you've not shown us. Please add the relevant code to the question

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see your code. Here is how to use blur and next

```js
$("#x").on("blur",function() {
  $(this).next().html(this.value ? "" : "please enter a value")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="x"><span></span>
```

Here is if they are not siblings

```js
$("#x").on("blur",function() {
  $(this).closest("div").next().html(this.value ? "" : "please enter a value")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input id="x">
</div>
<span></span>
```